# A larger heap for the Gradle daemon is recommended for running jack

Tags: android, gradle, jack

Im pretty new to gradle. I currently tried to upgrade a study Android app to Java 1.8 in gradle settings in which it prompted me to enable jackOptions to 'true' so i could use lambda expressions in my app.

This is my current gradle options:

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    dexOptions{
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bmw.www.team10"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        jackOptions{
            enabled true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
}
```

gradle.properties

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

When i try to build my project, this loops for 10 minutes in the gradle console

```
A larger heap for the Gradle daemon is recommended for running jack.

It currently has 1024 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to at least 1536 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

uncomment this line in gradle.properties :

```
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

to

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: Bahahahahaha! I feel so stupid. I spent 4 hours and it was all over a stupid hash tag. Thanks man. I need to take a week to just really learn about gradle